# Understanding Heap graph from visualvm

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory, visualvm

I have a program which essentially reads many files (mixed PDF usually below 10 MB + XML size of Kb) from disk and upload them one at a time into a legacy system.  I let it run under visualvm when going on weekend, and this morning I came back to a graph showing that the heap usage was rather uneven in the hour it took the program to run.  I was expecting a roughly level amount of heap usage over time.

[image: heap graph from visualvm showing an uneven heap pressure over time]

I am looking for an explanation for this.  This is with 64-bit Oracle JVM under Ubuntu 17.04 (Desktop, not server) with 32 GB RAM on a 4-core i5-2400 (no hyperthreading).  The program is essentially single-threaded utilizing about 50% of a core and took an expected time to run.

I understand that if memory is not fully used it is released over time.  I do not understand that the usage goes down over time, as the load should be quite evenly distributed.  Am I seeing the result of the CPU throttling as the system is otherwise idle?  Is some JVM optimization kicking in?

Answer (score 2):

Actual GC logs would be more helpful, but it's probably just the GC heuristics adjusting their decisions about young and old heap size to meet throughput and pause time goals.

As long as you don't place limits on the JVM it will happily use more memory than the bare minimum to keep the program running. If it did not you would experience very very frequent and inefficient GCs. In other words, *heap size = n * live object set size* with *n* > 1. Depending on the collector used there may be no upper limit for n other than available memory since ParallelGC defaults `MaxHeapFreeRatio` to 100 while G1 uses 70.

The heuristics are far from perfect, they can paint themselves into a corner in some edge-cases or unnecessarily fluctuate between different equilibrium points. But the graph itself does not indicate a problem.

Comment: I am not thinking this is a problem.  I am trying to learn how things _normally_ look (and why) to be able to recognize when they don't look normal anymore.  This is using all the defaults of the JVM.  I could enable gc logging at a later run if it would get anything useful.  Do you have a link to a good resource discussing these GC heuristics?

Comment: the [tag:garbage-collection] tag [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/garbage-collection/info) has links to some resources